# Key binding to `C-<` and `C->` not working when creating minor mode

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, minor-mode, quote, backquote

I wrote a couple of functions to automatically convert sequences like `"<<"` in `«`. (Yeah, I know that input methods can do the same, but I don't want the extra bindings: I'm planning to use a lot of apostrophes, and I don't want them to be joined).
So far, I have my functions:

```lisp
(defun electric-left-angle ()
  "Insert a left angle bracket ('<') and, if doubles, converts it to an open guillemet ('«')."
  (interactive)
  (if (equal (char-before (point)) #x3c);;code for <
      (progn
    (delete-char -1) ;;TODO see doc
    (insert-char #x00ab 1 t)) ;;code for «
    (insert-char #x3c 1 t)))

(defun electric-right-angle ()
  "Insert a right angle bracket ('>') and, if double, converts it to a close guillemet ('»')."
  (interactive)
  (if (equal (char-before (point)) #x3e);;code for >
      (progn
    (delete-char -1) ;;TODO see doc
    (insert-char #x00bb 1 t)) ;;code for »
    (insert-char #x3e 1 t)))
```

which works fine.

Then I thought "What if I want to insert a literal sequence `<<`? So I also created these:

```lisp
(defun quoted-insert-left-angle-bracket ()
  "Insert the quoted char '<'."
  (interactive)
  (progn (insert-char #x3c 1 t)))

(defun quoted-insert-right-angle-bracket ()
  "Insert the quoted char '>'."
  (interactive)
  (progn (insert-char #x3e 1 t)))
```

and these works fine too.

The problem arises when I try to bind these functions in a custom minor mode:

```lisp
(define-minor-mode narrative-mode
  "A minor mode that overrides the angle brackets insertion, changing them to guillemets.

Binds '<' and '>' to specific functions, which converts \"<<\" to '«' and \">>\" to '»'. Normal angle brackets can be inserted with C-< and C->."
  :lighter " narr"
  :keymap '(((kbd "<") . electric-left-angle)
        ((kbd ">") . electric-right-angle)
        ((kbd "C-<") . quoted-insert-left-angle-bracket)
        ((kbd "C->") . quoted-insert-right-angle-bracket)))
```

When I activate this mode, pressing  <kbd><</kbd>   <kbd><</kbd>  does indeed insert `«`. But pressing  <kbd>C</kbd>  +  <kbd><</kbd>  reports `C-< is undefined` in the echo area. **Why?**

---

### Further information

Notice that investigating with `C-h k C-<` gives `C-< is undefined`, but `C-h f quoted-insert-left-angle` gives

```
quoted-insert-left-angle-bracket is an interactive Lisp function in
‘../init.el’.

It is bound to C - <.

(quoted-insert-left-angle-bracket)

Insert the quoted char ’<’.
```

(notice the unusual **odd space** in `"C - <"`.

Moreover, assigning the function globally with `(global-set-key (kbd "C-<") #'quoted-insert-left-angle-bracket)` **works fine**, so I suppose it's a problem of how I bind the functions in the minor mode.

I'm using `GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.27, cairo version 1.17.4) of 2021-03-26.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually have expected <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> not to work either. What you need to pass to `:keymap` is a list where each element is a cons pair of a key and a binding. A “key” is something you can pass to [`define-key`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings.html#index-define_002dkey), i.e. an [event type](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Lookup.html). What you're passing as the key is `(kbd "<")`, which is a 2-element list whose car is `kbd`. This is not a listed event type, so I would have expected an error.

It just happens that what you passed as the key is a Lisp expression which, when evaluated, returns a valid event type. But that's not valid here. You need to pass the value of that expression.

A simple solution (untested) is to use a [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) and unquote the expressions you want to evaluate. And of course for something simple like `(kbd "<")`, you don't need `kbd` at all.

```
  :keymap `(("<" . electric-left-angle)
            (">" . electric-right-angle)
            (,(kbd "C-<") . quoted-insert-left-angle-bracket)
            (,(kbd "C->") . quoted-insert-right-angle-bracket)))
```

Comment: *"What you're passing as the key is (kbd "<"), which is a 2-element list whose car is kbd. This is not a listed event type, so I would have expected an error."* But the same applies to `(kbd "<")`, no? That too needs to be evaluated.

Comment: @Drew Yes, I don't understand why it's working. But it's not evaluating `(kbd "<")` as a function call: you can pass `(foo "<")` and it “works” too in that it's equivalent to "<".

Comment: Yes, I agree. Your answer is correct. But the "tolerance" (if that's what it is) of `(kbd "<")` is confusing, and can lead (did lead) to the confusion about `(kbd "C-<")`. (And I think *"something you can pass to `define-key`"* is itself misleading. This needs to be worded in some unambiguous way - in the doc, for example. It's possible to "pass" `(kbd "C->")` to `define-key` - it all depends on how one interprets "passing" something to a function.

Comment: This worked out, thanks to both. Tried in my config, `(kbd "<")` evaluates to `"<"`, while `(kbd "C-<")` evaluates to `[67108924]`. Maybe is this the cause of the difference? Single-char sequences evaluates to themselves, making them effectively suitable to be placed in the bindings list